# Find me all inputs where ID ends with xyz except for a particular ID

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find a way to do the following:

find all input elements where the ID ends with "__Name". I do so with this:

```
var desiredElements = $("input[id$='__Name']");
```

I however now want all of the above elements found EXCEPT for one which ends with a particular ID

How would I do this? To get all input type elements where an ID ends in xyz except for a particular given one? (such as: _1__xyz)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var desiredElements = $("input[id$='__Name']").not("input[id$=_1__xyz]");
```

Comment: Or simply `var desiredElements = $("input[id$='__Name']").not("#_1__xyz")`, no need for complexity if the OP says he's using a complete `id`.

Comment: You are right, unless he does not want elements with id ending with _1__xyz

Comment: The original answer here worked great. Thank you! I was looking for ids which do not end with a particular ID (ends with).